# OLE DB Database Connectivity with R

Tags: r, oledb, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect to an `iHistorian` Database.  This database is a product of `GE` and it records process control information.  Anyway, this database is configured with `OLE DB` drivers.  I am curious if there is a way to connect to this database with `R`.  Currently, `R` has a package called `RODBC`, but this package only connects to `ODBC`.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately you may be out of luck, seeing as OLE DB is now a deprecated API. I'd be surprised if iHistorian didn't support ODBC though, as it's pervasive and cross-platform.

Comment: Hi Hong, unfortunately after looking through manuals and computer files. iHistorian is only using OLE DB.  I was curious whether I can embed C++/# code in my R code and use the OLE DB connection from the embedded code to get data.  Or is this too much of a stretch?